# Search all files in repository for pattern in Perforce

Tags: perforce

Is there a way to search a repository for a pattern that could be contained in one or more code files...

i.e I have the an application, that has a dev, UAT and Prod folders, under each of these there are multiple sub-folders for the code, resource [images, etc], binaries, etc. The program has maybe 100 different code file (.java, .cs, .net, .egl, etc). I would want to click on the application root and do a search for a specific string within each of these files, without having to click on each file.

Is this doable?

I have tried to do the suggestion at https://www.perforce.com/blog/vcs/how-add-grep-command-search-your-helix-core-depot but that only seems to look for file names not the content within a file.

TYIA

Comment: Sorry I guess I was not clear on what I was trying to accomplish.  In this case we have 40 application on the Perforce server and I need to search through all 40 of them for a code pattern. It is not feasible to bring all the code into my local workspace to search through them.  I need something that will work on searching the remote server for the pattern(s) I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `p4 grep`.

https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v18.1/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_grep.html

e.g.:

```
p4 grep -e "a pattern" //depot/path/to/my/app/...
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you take a look at the silver searcher. https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

It's a tool that lets your recursively walk over files and highlight matches. It's like grep, but works over a directory and provides line numbers of the results.